# How to use EventBus in two Activity on Android

Tags: java, android, android-event, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

In my application i want use **EventBus** for manage events.
In my app i open **activity B** on the **Activity A** ! and i want when **activity B** finished, call one event in **Activity A**.

I write below codes

**Activity B :**

```
private void finishWithAnimate() {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventShowDialog(ExtraConstants.NOTE_DIALOG.name()));
    if (pageType.equals(Extras.DETAIL)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(4757, intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        finish();
        RegisterInAuctionActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(0, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }
}
```

**Activity A :**

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void getEventShowDialog(EventShowDialog eventShowDialog) {
    Log.e("showDialogEvent", "Root");
    if (eventShowDialog.getDialogName().equals(ExtraConstants.NOTE_DIALOG.name())) {
        Log.e("showDialogEvent", "Call");
        if (!prefsUtils.getFromSharedBool(PrefsKeys.NEW_NOTE_DIALOG.name())) {
            closeDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    noteDialog.dismiss();
                    prefsUtils.setToSharedBool(PrefsKeys.NEW_NOTE_DIALOG.name(), true);
                }
            });
            noteDialog.show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

**Update codes:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 4757) {
        //Note dialog
        noteDialog = new Dialog(this);
        noteDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        noteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.important_note);
        noteDialog.setCancelable(false);
        closeDialog = noteDialog.findViewById(R.id.okPayFrag_submitOK);
        closeDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                noteDialog.dismiss();
                prefsUtils.setToSharedBool(PrefsKeys.NEW_NOTE_DIALOG.name(), true);
            }
        });
        if (!prefsUtils.getFromSharedBool(PrefsKeys.NEW_NOTE_DIALOG.name())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            noteDialog.show();
            closeDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    noteDialog.dismiss();
                    prefsUtils.setToSharedBool(PrefsKeys.NEW_NOTE_DIALOG.name(), true);
                }
            });
        }
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, 0);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, 0);
    }
}
```

But not call any log in `getEventShowDialog` . Not show me any log in this method!

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to perform some actions on getting a result from an activity.
So when your activity B finishes, do a setResult and catch the same on Activity A onActivityResult and perform your action(call the function you want).
You need to do a startActivityForResult while opening B from A though.

Comment: How can i it? can you show me code with my codes? please

Comment: I write below code :                                 `Intent intent = new Intent(context, RegisterInAuctionActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra(ExtraConstants.SHOW_UPDATE_INFO.name(), false);
                                intent.putExtra(ExtraConstants.PAGE_TYPE.name(), Extras.DETAIL.name());
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 4757);`

Comment: Yes, and then from your Activity B, you do something like this

When B finishes:
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("NAME OF THE PARAMETER", valueOfParameter);
...
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();

In A:
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1) { // Please, use a final int instead of hardcoded int value
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
// call your function.
        }

Comment: I want call eventBus, why not call it? how can i fix it and call this?

Comment: You dont need a EventBus here, just use setResult as I mentioned and your code would work fine.

Comment: I want show Dialog in Activity A and for this call method from another activities, for this way i should use EventBus

Comment: Once you get the result back in onActivityResult() in Activity A, you can do anything , in your case showing a dialog.

Comment: When show dialog in onActivityResult method show me nullPointer error for show! how can i fix it?

Comment: Could you share your code and show me where exactly its throwing null pointer ?

Comment: please show my update post, show me Toast message but not show dialog! why?!

Comment: Are you here my friend? can you help me?

Comment: You need to check result code inside onActivityResult in place of requestCode.